# launch4j wrapper starts twice

Tags: java, launch4j

I wrapped my java application with launch4j.

When I start the launcher, the app starts as usual. after ca. 5 seconds the application closes and restarts without any visible reason.

Here the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
<dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
<jar>.\app\getdown-1.4.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\dev\repos\myproject\build\getdown\launch.exe</outfile>
<errTitle>Fehler - myproject</errTitle>
  <cmdLine>./app</cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
<priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
<stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
<manifest></manifest>
  <icon>C:\dev\repos\myproject\build\getdown\app\favicon.ico</icon>
<singleInstance>
<mutexName>myproject</mutexName>
    <windowTitle>myproject</windowTitle>
</singleInstance>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
<bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
<maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
<runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: please, what is your environment? I have similar problem on Windows 8.1 64bit using 32bit JDK. I have "console" type app and when I run exe from `cmd` it first runs in separate window and even if it starts normally it is interrupted (so far unknown reasons, not even shutdown hooks are run so it seems). Right after this second cmd window closes, it starts the app again in my original cmd. There it runs normally. Also funny fact - first time it does not appear in `jps` output (if you manage to "catch" it), but the second time it does.

Comment: never mind I found your report https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/135/ and I'll continue there or in new issue.

Comment: yes, I created this one ;)

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's kinda silly, but in my case it was Avast Cybersomething - antivirus secure environment. Make sure your app is not running in similar, isolated env before it runs normaly.

Comment: This should be a comment.